# Почему возникает ошибка IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python

```
d = open('C:\\Users\\79954\\Desktop\\Новая папка\\output.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=';')
writer.writerows(matrix)
d.close()
```

Comment: А что в этом скрипте происходит? Что бы не закрывать файл - используйте конструкцию: with open('path_to_file', 'mode') as f:

Comment: Ошибка говорит о лишнем о отступе, но в приведенном коде отступов вообще нет, и он не может вызывать данную ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка с отступами у Вас.. лучше использовать такую конструкцию, что бы быть уверенным в том, что файл будет закрыт и не использовать d.close()

```
with open('C:\\Users\\79954\\Desktop\\Новая папка\\output.csv', 'w') as f:
  do_some_magic_here()
```